# Два процесса слушают один порт на всех интерфейсах, как такое возможно?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, сеть, jetty

Windows 8.1 Профессиональная
Запущен и работает tomcat (7.0.72.0 JVM 1.7.0_13-b20) на порту 8080
Запустил HelloWorld-пример на jetty:

```js
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

public class WebServer extends AbstractHandler {
public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.setHandler(new WebServer());
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

}

Стартует без ошибок:

```
2017-02-01 12:21:02.029:INFO::main: Logging initialized @132ms
2017-02-01 12:21:02.075:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.20.v20161216
2017-02-01 12:21:02.116:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@2b6dd9c5{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2017-02-01 12:21:02.117:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @222ms
```

Видим, что порт открылся, но отвечает конечно же tomcat:

> D:\>netstat -ano|find /i "8080"
>
> TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5536
>
> TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2464
>
> TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       5536

> D:\>tasklist|find /i "tom"
>
>     tomcat7.exe                   2464 Services                   0   185 916 КБ

> D:\>tasklist|find /i "java"
>
> javaw.exe                     5536 Console                    1    26 864 КБ

Если создавать сервер исключительно на IPv4 адресе:

server = new Server(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080));

Exception выбрасывается

но если создать так:

server = new Server(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", 8080));

то Exception **не выбрасывается** и прослушиваются порты и IPv4 и IPv6

Таким образом, программа не может вовремя определить, что порт занят кем-то и уведомить пользователя.

Answer (score 2):

Конечная точка TCP состоит из IP-адреса и порта, поэтому 127.0.0.1:8080 и 0.0.0.0:8080 - это **разные** конечные точки. Насколько я понимаю, 127.0.0.1:8080 у вас занята томкатом, в то время как 0.0.0.0:8080 свободна. Поэтому вы получаете исключение когда пытаетесь слушать 127.0.0.1:8080, но успешно слушаете 0.0.0.0:8080.

Теперь к чему это приводит. Клиент соединяется с сервером используя определенные IP-адрес и порт, то есть конечную точку. Поэтому, соединяясь с 127.0.0.1:8080, он всегда попадает на томкат. Но это не значит, что связаться с вашей программой невозможно - ведь у компьютера есть и другие IP-адреса!

Например, можно использовать адрес 127.0.0.2: `http://127.0.0.2:8080/`. Если ни одна другая программа не слушает конечную точку 127.0.0.2:8080 - такой запрос попадёт к программе, которая слушает 0.0.0.0:8080.

Или же можно использовать IP-адрес, назначенный любому сетевому интерфейсу. Фактически, любой запрос из сети попадёт именно в вашу программу, а не в томкат, потому что по сети невозможно связаться с "чужим" адресом 127.0.0.1.